# JUnit 5 extension for starting Tomcat 9 with codehaus cargo fails

Tags: java, maven, junit, cargo, junit5-extension-model

I fail to use a Tomcat container with codehaus's `cargo-maven3-plugin` in version 1.10.7. It's using Java 11. When I execute the code that follows I get this exception which seems to me that downloading and installing the Tomcat container works. The exceptions happens in the line of `Configuration config = configFactory.createConfiguration(containerId, ContainerType.INSTALLED, ConfigurationType.RUNTIME);`

I've debugged to that point and can see that a certain mapping is missing but I have no idea where to get this mapping.

```
org.codehaus.cargo.container.ContainerException: Cannot create configuration. There's no registered configuration for the parameters (container [id = [tomcat9x], type = [installed]], configuration type [runtime]). Actually there are no valid types registered for this configuration. Maybe you've made a mistake spelling it?

    at org.codehaus.cargo.generic.spi.AbstractGenericHintFactory.createImplementation(AbstractGenericHintFactory.java:135)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.generic.spi.AbstractIntrospectionGenericHintFactory.createImplementation(AbstractIntrospectionGenericHintFactory.java:89)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.generic.configuration.DefaultConfigurationFactory.createConfiguration(DefaultConfigurationFactory.java:165)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.generic.configuration.DefaultConfigurationFactory.createConfiguration(DefaultConfigurationFactory.java:152)
    at com.example.TomcatExtension.afterAll(TomcatExtension.java:41)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeAfterAllCallbacks$16(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:447)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeAfterAllCallbacks$17(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:447)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeAfterAllCallbacks(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:447)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.after(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:229)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.after(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:161)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:161)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:232)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:55)
```

I've break down my problem to this easy reproducible code. The project is initialized with IntelliJ. The `pom.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>cargotest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.14.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cargo-maven3-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.7</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

My test stub (not doing anything except for calling the extension):

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;

@ExtendWith(TomcatExtension.class)
class WarTest {

    @Test
    void test() {
    }
}
```

The JUnit5 extension that should create a Tomcat 9 container:

```java
import org.codehaus.cargo.container.ContainerType;
import org.codehaus.cargo.container.InstalledLocalContainer;
import org.codehaus.cargo.container.configuration.Configuration;
import org.codehaus.cargo.container.configuration.ConfigurationType;
import org.codehaus.cargo.container.installer.Proxy;
import org.codehaus.cargo.container.installer.ZipURLInstaller;
import org.codehaus.cargo.generic.DefaultContainerFactory;
import org.codehaus.cargo.generic.configuration.DefaultConfigurationFactory;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.AfterAllCallback;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.BeforeAllCallback;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtensionContext;

import java.net.URL;

public class TomcatExtension implements BeforeAllCallback, AfterAllCallback {

    private InstalledLocalContainer _container;

    @Override
    public void afterAll(ExtensionContext extensionContext) throws Exception {

        ZipURLInstaller installer;
        try {
            String url = "https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat/9.0.76/tomcat-9.0.76.zip";
            installer = new ZipURLInstaller(new URL(url));
            Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
            proxy.setHost("proxy host");
            proxy.setPort(8080);
            installer.setProxy(proxy);
            installer.download();
            installer.install();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not install Tomcat.", ex);
        }

        String containerId = "tomcat9x";
        var configFactory = new DefaultConfigurationFactory();
        var containerFactory = new DefaultContainerFactory();
        Configuration config = configFactory.createConfiguration(containerId, ContainerType.INSTALLED, ConfigurationType.RUNTIME);
        InstalledLocalContainer tomcat9x = (InstalledLocalContainer) containerFactory.createContainer("tomcat9x", ContainerType.INSTALLED, config);
        tomcat9x.setHome(installer.getHome());
        _container = tomcat9x;
        _container.start();
    }

    // void beforeAll(): stop the container
}
```

Comment: First `Actually there are no valid types registered for this configuration.` furthermore having a plugin as a dependency is wrong... and where is the cargo-maven3-plugin configured in your build?